# Can we write a custom target in ant?

Tags: java, ant

However we can create our own tasks using taskdef (as explained here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ant/ant_extending_ant.htm).

I want to have a custom target like `<customtarget name="customtarget">` where we can execute the target from command line as we usually do for `<target>`.

For Ex: `<target name="sometarget">`, we do `ant sometarget` in the same way i should be able to do `ant customtarget`.

Like custom tasks can we have custom targets ??

Comment: Your question is completely unclear. Why `<target name="customtarget">` does not satisfy you? Are you mixing targets and tasks?

Comment: i want to have a custom target where i can modify/enhance the functionality of the target as required.  As we can have a custom tasks can we have a custom targets ?

Comment: I suppose you're looking for macrodef => https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/macrodef.html or presetdef => https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/presetdef.html